# Inno Setup Check Internet Connection

Tags: networking, inno-setup

I use sponsors banners in wizard, which open website in browser. 
So I need to check the internet connection before setup. 
If internet is turn off break the installation with some message.
How to do that?

If I understand correctly, I simply need to ping any url like google.

Comment: Do a simple GET request. Ideally not to Google but directly to your sponsor's server because even if you'll be able to reach Google, the sponsor's server may be dead (or vice-versa). There will be some examples on how to make a GET request (maybe phrased like "how to download a file") over here.

Comment: And please note that if you use that method and the site you check is down, people can't continue the installation. It might seem obvious but can be very irritating if you can't continue with an installation and don't know why. Even if you say it's because it has no internet connection it would be a direct no-no for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check Internet connection using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291191/how-to-check-internet-connection-using-inno-setup)