# How to check Internet connection using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, internet-connection

I'm learning about Inno Setup to make a simple installer. I need to download a file from a website during the installation, so it's important check if there is Internet connection. How can I check or take some alert to connect Internet during the process of the installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best check is to try to actually download the file.

"Internet" is hardly a real thing that you can connect to. So it's hard to test, if you are connected to "Internet". You actually do not need a connection to "Internet", you need a connection to your server. So test that.

---

See also

- [How to check if internet connection is present in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1402005/850848)
- [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2031824/850848)

An equivalent implementation in Inno Setup would be like:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  Connected: Boolean;
begin
  Connected := False;
  repeat
    Log('Checking connection to the server');
    try
      WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
      { Use your real server host name }
      WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'https://www.example.com/', False);
      WinHttpReq.Send('');
      Log('Connected to the server; status: ' + IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status) + ' ' +
          WinHttpReq.StatusText);
      Connected := True;
    except
      Log('Error connecting to the server: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
      if WizardSilent then
      begin
        Log('Connection to the server is not available, aborting silent installation');
        Result := False;
        Exit;
      end
        else
      if MsgBox('Cannot reach server. Please check your Internet connection.',
                mbError, MB_RETRYCANCEL) = IDRETRY then
      begin
        Log('Retrying');
      end
        else
      begin
        Log('Aborting');
        Result := False;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  until Connected;

  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: So, you recommend to make for example simple Java or .NET script which test for Internet connection (making a ping...) and run it from InnoSetup before to start the installation?

Comment: No, I suggest you implement that logic in Inno Setup Pascal Script. I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks so much!